# minimal cd install problem 32-bit

Tags: xubuntu, cd, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install xubuntu from the ubuntu minimal cd, but hit a wall when it "loading additional components." This happens at 18 %. I understand that I can install the xubuntu desktop this way, but I am stopped at this point. My computer is :
Dell Opti-plex GX-200
Intel Pentium III - 933 Mhz.
1024 Ram
on board Nvidia graphics chip
140 Gb hard drive @ 7200 r.p.m.
Any help you might give me would be much appreciated.
Thank you.
creek

Comment: How long did you let it sit there?

Comment: It's possible that that machine is just simply too old.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may be old. I am currently running Tharpup and it purrs and it should run xubuntu. When the installation comes to an end is at 18% and then it goes to retry, change mirror, or cancel. None of the mirrors work ( none in North America or the U.K.)

Answer (score 0):

Straingly about 2 years later... "still stuck at 18%" ???

Probable reasons:

1. Your CD is BADlY burned !!!! (errors on it)
2. Your CD Reader is bad (change it)
3. Your HDD \ ide in this machine is bad (Low-format it)
4. Bad Hardware, connections, wires, CPU overheat, RAM Defect..
5. TRIPLE-CHECK every pieces of hardware you use in this machine.

this machine is more than able run this "minimal CD os" :)